# FFmpeg: A few errors including invalid frame size and incomplete frame

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, command-prompt, dvd

I use this ffmpeg command to take clips from a large VOB files that is on a DVD:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i E:\VTS_02_2.vob -ss 00:00:57 -t 00:16:15 vids\VTS_02_2.vob
```

It worked first for a VOB file but then I got these errors:

```
c:\ffmpeg>ffmpeg.exe -i E:\VTS_02_2.vob -ss 00:00:57 -t 00:16:15 vids\VTS_02_2.vob
FFmpeg version SVN-r15625, Copyright (c) 2000-2008 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --enable-memalign-hack --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-g
l --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libv
rbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --disable-ffserver --disabl
-vhook --enable-avisynth --enable-pthreads
  libavutil     49.12. 0 / 49.12. 0
  libavcodec    52. 0. 0 / 52. 0. 0
  libavformat   52.22. 1 / 52.22. 1
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  libswscale     0. 6. 1 /  0. 6. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Oct 16 2008 05:40:02, gcc: 4.2.4 (TDM-1 for MinGW)
Input #0, mpeg, from 'E:\VTS_02_2.vob':
  Duration: 00:17:11.61, start: 1031.828511, bitrate: 8326 kb/s
    Stream #0.0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video, yuv420p, 720x576 [PAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 9640
kb/s, 25.00 tb(r)
    Stream #0.1[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 192 kb/s
File 'vids\VTS_02_2.vob' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, svcd, to 'vids\VTS_02_2.vob':
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg2video, yuv420p, 720x576 [PAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200
kb/s, 25.00 tb(c)
    Stream #0.1: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop encoding
[ac3 @ 026D3990]frame sync error
Error while decoding stream #0.1
frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
[mpeg2video @ 0141B780]ac-tex damaged at 40 2
[mpeg2video @ 0141B780]invalid mb type in B Frame at 3 12
[mpeg2video @ 0141B780]00 motion_type at 15 16
[mpeg2video @ 0141B780]mb incr damaged
[mpeg2video @ 0141B780]00 motion_type at 2 21
[mpeg2video @ 0141B780]00 motion_type at 44 22
[mpeg2video @ 0141B780]ac-tex damaged at 43 24
[mpeg2video @ 0141B780]Warning MVs not available
[mpeg2video @ 0141B780]concealing 765 DC, 765 AC, 765 MV errors
frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
[mpeg2video @ 0141B780]ac-tex damaged at 5 9
[mpeg2video @ 0141B780]00 motion_type at 21 13
[mpeg2video @ 0141B780]ac-tex damaged at 1 20
[mpeg2video @ 0141B780]mb incr damaged
[mpeg2video @ 0141B780]00 motion_type at 30 30
[mpeg2video @ 0141B780]Warning MVs not available
[mpeg2video @ 0141B780]concealing 450 DC, 450 AC, 450 MV errors
[ac3 @ 026D3990]frame CRC mismatch
[ac3 @ 026D3990]incomplete frame
[ac3 @ 026D3990]invalid frame size
frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
[mpeg2video @ 0141B780]00 motion_type at 38 15
[mpeg2video @ 0141B780]00 motion_type at 30 34
[mpeg2video @ 0141B780]Warning MVs not available
[mpeg2video @ 0141B780]concealing 254 DC, 254 AC, 254 MV errors
frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
[mpeg2video @ 0141B780]ac-tex damaged at 7 6
[mpeg2video @ 0141B780]concealing 1350 DC, 1350 AC, 1350 MV errors
frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
[ac3 @ 026D3990]incomplete frame
[ac3 @ 026D3990]invalid frame size
frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s

video:0kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead -1.#IND00%
```

**Is there a way to force ffmpeg to just give me an output?**

Comment: The above is coming from a person that asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317046/why-doesnt-your-company-contribute-back-to-open-source

Comment: Either answer my question or keep quiet. Don't ruin this thread.

Comment: I see that you have deleted your comments. This person: http://stackoverflow.com/users/23691/krosenvold said stop asking questions not related to programming while he himself starts questions not related to programming. Just for the record. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lines that start with [mpeg2video @ 0141B780] show general decoding errors.  Sometimes these are nothing to worry about because FFMPEG successfully keeps going on after such errors (the errors may apply only to the current frame); they may represent glitches in the encoder used to encode the source, or even transfer errors.

Of concern here, though, are all the zeros in the other lines:

```
frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
```

It seems to be having trouble making sense of the source.  What does [Media Info](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) tell you about the source VOB?

This community may not be very well geared towards solving audio/video encoding issues - have you tried doom9.org?  You may need to get someone to have a look at a sample of the source VOB for you.

Presumably you are using the command line version of ffmpeg because you want to automate this; if not, note that tools such as AVIdemux could do this in a GUI too.  Despite its name it can copy MPEG without re-encoding.